# Will moment.js Timezone Account for DST?

Tags: momentjs

I'm setting up a simple interface where the user can view the time of a scheduled webinar in their time zone by selecting it from a dropdown menu. The start time of the webinar will update dynamically based on the timezone the user has selected. I'm using this script with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [moment-timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone):

```
var timestamp = $('.overview .date').data('timestamp');

var utcDate = moment.unix(timestamp).utc();

$('.modal.timezone select').on('change', function(){
  var timezone = $(this).val();

  var tzDate = utcDate.tz(timezone);

  var formattedTime = tzDate.format("h:mm A");

  var formattedTimezone = tzDate.format("z");

  $('.modal.timezone .time').html("<strong>" + formattedTime + " </strong>" + formattedTimezone);
});
```

This works well; the time is updated to the selected timezone. But what I'm wondering is will this still work when DST kicks in, or will the webinar times display one hour off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't doing anything here that uses the *current* time, so there's nothing that would change on its own.

Even then, you are feeding a UTC value into moment-timezone which uses the DST rules corresponding to *that* time zone - not your own.

So you should be fine.  If you are unsure, you can always test it out by changing your local computer's clock to just before the DST change for wherever you're located and see what happens.